# Javascript if else statement optimisation

Tags: javascript

I want to ask about optimisation in JavaScript `if else` statement.I have the code like this

```
if ( thisIsTrue )
    printMe("someMessage");
```

And the code can be optimisation like this

```
thisIsTrue && printMe("someMessage");
```

The question is what the code of `thisIsTrue && printMe("someMessage");` only works in statement who has been return true.

What if the return is false?

Comment: What about `!thisIsFalse && printMe("someMessage")`. However, this is not really an optimization; all it does is make the code more difficult to read. I would go with your first example, and add braces too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
thisIsTrue ? printMe("is true") : printMe("is false");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer you true... and i got it with function like this `thisIsTrue ? theTruthFunction() : theFalseFunction();`

Answer (score 13):

You should avoid turning your code into a puzzle either for someone else, or for the future you.  There is nothing to be gained from mixing your conditions with your output. It's not going to "optimize" anything, and it will cost you lots of time in the future as you try to debug this.

I would argue you should err on the side of MORE verbosity not less.

Comment: +1 although I think more verbosity is never the right goal, but more clarity is. Actually verbosity isn't a desired attribute of programs at all (simple and succinct programs are awesome), but when a choice has to be made between either clarity and verbosity, then clarity always wins.

Comment: Note that some JS compressors will turn if statements into one of `a&&b`, `a||b`, `a?b:c` automatically (like uglifyjs), further negating the need to write code like this "because you can".  Also note that _normal_ if statements are _faster_ than any of the above in modern browsers

Comment: certainly that's what I meant... I'm not suggesting anyone should go out of their way to make their programs longer, but if you're torn between sticking your i++ into a really clever spot where you're SURE it's the last time you're using i before it needs to increment, I'm willing to bed cash money that this will eventually bite you in the arse. Just put it on its own line. The future you will thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not optimisation and not suggested but i would explain the details.

in a combination of operands like `A && B` , `1st` the `operand A` will be executed and if it `return true` the `second operand` will be executed otherwise it will be terminated because  if the `1st operand` is `true` the `result` will depends on the `second operand` else if the `1st` is `false` `result` will surely be `false` irrespective of the second operand so it doesnot execute the second one. so

```
true && alert("someMessage"); will show alert
```

and

```
!false && alert("someMessage....."); will also show
```

combinding the above two, you can write is as

```
condition ? alert("someMessage") : alert("someMessage.....");
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9q2jC/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is hardly an optimisation (in terms of performance).

Also, these two forms are not identical.

The latter is an expression, while the former is a statement.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have a series of If-Then-Else statements, you should try your best to organize them from most likely to least likely. This way the program doesn't have to traverse all the unlikely conditions to get to the likely ones, which will be called more often.
>
> A commonly used tactic to wring whatever overhead might be left out of a large group of simple conditional statements is replacing If-Then-Else's with Switch statements. This is a tough one to qualify. Performance varies widely, although you almost always come out with some kind of improvement, even if it is small. As always, proper code design is much more important. See there are good [test cases](http://home.earthlink.net/~kendrasg/info/js_opt/jsOptMain.html) with switch and if elseif else